# navigation li to create <span></span> around text via jquery

Tags: jquery, append, html, prepend

I've been trying all day and reading a few things, but for some reason my code isn't working right

What i'm trying to achieve is this:  When i create an un ordered list in my index page - I want my jquery to automatically add  around the text in the anchor.  So i want it to look like this

```
<li><a href="index.htm"><span>Home</span></a></li>
```

while I am only adding:

```
<li><a href="index.htm">Home</a></li>
```

I want to do this because i have a LOT of list items and instead of writing  when i'm adding pages it makes the most sense to save some time in the long run and create a loop that will handle that anytime i add one.

This is What i have so far (sorry if it looks ugly):

```
$('document').ready(function () {
    var begSpan = "<span>";
    var endSpan = "</span>";
    $('p').each(function () {
        $(this) prepend(begSpan);
    }).append(endSpan);
});
```

How can i get that to auto create span tags for me

Comment: There are a couple errors in your code: `$('document')` shouldn't have quotes around it; you're selecting paragraph elements when apparently you want anchor elements. These things I've posted as fixed in my answer. There's also a syntax error there (missing a dot before the `prepend` call).

Comment: Thank you for showing me the code Errors! i've been staring at it too long I would never have caught the missing dot before the prepend!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is [.wrapInner()](http://api.jquery.com/wrapInner/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('li a').wrapInner('<span/>');
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/3hW3j/)

Comment: +1, I didn't pay enough attention to the requested DOM structure.

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('li a').wrapInner('<span/>');
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/j82Rt/1/)

[`.wrapInner()` docs](http://api.jquery.com/wrapInner/)

I'd also suggest using a more specific selector (e.g. `#menuId li a`) for future-proofness.

---

My original answer used `.wrap()` which would generate a `li > span > a` DOM structure, however your requested structure seems to be `li > a > span` which can be achieved with `.wrapInner()`.

Answer (score 1):

Use [.wrap()](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('li > a').wrap('<span>');
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/db4tB/)